# Water pressure/flow intermittently slow and cold water hammer intermittently

Tags: plumbing

My kitchen sink, and nowhere else, has recently developed two problems which are probably related.

Both the hot and cold water will often be very low flow and pressure. Turning off and back on sometimes fixes it. The speed with which the knob is turned appears to matter, faster knob turn means better water flow sometimes. Other times it stays slow, but then is fine a minute or hour later. On the hot side, when it's slow then turning the knob on half way produces no water flow, like the minimum point on the knob has been changed, but on the cold side the knob is still proportionally responsive just slower.

Also the cold water causes loud hammering noises (centered a couple of rooms away, along the plumbing to the kitchen) when turned on partially, again only sometimes. Turning it to a different setting always fixes it.

Everything seems fine at other faucets in the house.

What might cause this? I've looked at some other questions about water hammer but they don't seem to fit these symptoms, especially the very low flow on the hot water. And questions about low flow tend to be about clogged pipes or faucets, but I think mine running fine most of the time means that's not the case.

Comment: your faucets are not working properly

Comment: @Ruskes I believe the OP question sort of answers your comment, he already knows that.

Comment: To start I would need to know the faucet thats connected to the incoming water supply, will be the faucet with the highest pressure, I need to know the pressure there?